# Why does limiting my virtual memory to 512MB with ulimit -v crash the JVM?

Tags: java, memory-management, ubuntu, ulimit

I am trying to enforce maximum memory a program can consume on a Unix system. I thought ulimit -v should do the trick. Here is a sample Java program I have written for testing :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EatMem {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Starting up...");
    System.out.println("Allocating 128 MB of Memory");
    List<byte[]> list = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    list.add(new byte[134217728]); //128 MB
    System.out.println("Done....");
  }
}
```

By default, my ulimit settings are (output of ulimit -a) :

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31398
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31398
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

When I execute my java program (java EatMem), it executes without any problems. Now I try to limit max memory available to any program launched in the current shell to 512MB by launching the following command :

```
ulimit -v 524288
```

ulimit -a output shows the limit to be set correctly (I suppose):

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31398
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31398
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 524288
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

If I now try to execute my java program, it gives me the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Ideally it should not happen as my Java program is only taking around 128MB of memory which is well within my specified ulimit parameters. If I change the arguments to my Java program as below:

```
java -Xmx256m EatMem
```

The program again works fine. While trying to give more memory than limited by ulimit like :

```
java -Xmx800m EatMem
```

results in expected error. Why the program fails to execute in the first case after setting ulimit ?

I have tried the above test on Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.0.4 with Java 1.6 and Java 7

Answer (score 3):

`ulimit -v` sets the maximum address space a program can use. This includes all shared memory like libraries, thread stack space, direct memory etc. As the JVM isn't designed to run in a limited virtual memory environment like this it may not lay itself out in an optimal way. i.e. because virtual memory is normally very, very cheap.  I suspect you have to set this value much higher to get the JVM to run.

BTW: The JVM allocates the maximum heap size on startup.

---

If I set `ulimit -v 524288` and attempt to do

Runs ok

```
java -mx64m -version
java -mx128m -version
java -mx256m -version
```

Crashes with a failure to malloc

```
java -mx300m -version
```

Error occured during initialization of VM

```
java -mx400m -version
java -mx512m -version
```

This is more or less expected behaviour.

Comment: Can you say what they are?

Comment: Sorry, re-writing the phrase as accidentally hit enter last time. Thanks @peter-lawrey for the explanation. But I am still not clear about why it still works when I pass -Xmx parameter explicitly ? BTW, When I try using ulimit -m 524288, it works as per the expectations i.e. when I try allocating 128MB of memory in the program, works without any issues but anything more than 512MB gets me an error.

Comment: I have added what I see from using ulimit -v. It behaves about as I would expect. Its worth remembering that the maximum heap size is NOT the maximum virtual memory used.

Comment: So does it mean, if I have to control the maximum memory a Java program can consume, ulimit -v is not the correct approach? Is ulimit -m a better option or there is something else I should consider ?

Comment: This may be closer to what you need because it controls actual memory used.  Using such a hard limit is dangerous because it will crash the JVM. It is better if you can set reasonable limits the JVM can monitor (either as well or instead of a hard limit)

Comment: which java version you used? I tried same commands you used and got `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes` My java version is `1.8.0_161`